# SQL Server-How can i replace a date column with a current date when the column has a NULL value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT ACTFINISH, TARGCOMPDATE, REPORTDATE,
    CASE 
       WHEN TARGCOMPDATE < ACTFINISH THEN 'Past Due'
       WHEN TARGCOMPDATE > ACTFINISH  THEN 'Past Due'
       WHEN ACTFINISH IS NULL --I want to use "Current Date" in a place of NULL to be able to compare with current date.
    END AS PERFORMANCE
FROM TICKET
```

Comment: in select can just do ISNULL(DateColumn, GetDate()) as Date

Comment: Hint:  `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ACTFINISH, TARGCOMPDATE, REPORTDATE,
CASE 
   WHEN TARGCOMPDATE < ACTFINISH THEN 'Past Due'
   WHEN TARGCOMPDATE > ACTFINISH  THEN 'Past Due'
   WHEN ACTFINISH IS NULL THEN CONVERT(date, getdate())
END AS PERFORMANCE FROM TICKET
```

Comment: WHEN ACTFINISH IS NULL I want to use "Current DateTime" in the 
           place of NULL value of ACTFINISH to be able to use it in comparison 
           expression.I wanted it to turn into Something like WHEN TARGCOMPDATE 
           > CURRENTDATETIME THEN 'On Time' and WHEN TARGCOMPDATE < CURRENTDATETIME 
           THEN 'Past Due" automatically everytime ACTFINISH has a NULL value.)

Answer (score 0):

Your column is not a *date* column.  It is a string column.

Hence, you don't want `GETDATE()` because a `case` expression returns a single type and if any of the return values are dates, then all will be converted to dates.

So, the query needs to convert the value to a string.  You can use the default formatting:

```
SELECT ACTFINISH, TARGCOMPDATE, REPORTDATE,
       (CASE WHEN TARGCOMPDATE < ACTFINISH THEN 'Past Due'
             WHEN TARGCOMPDATE > ACTFINISH  THEN 'Past Due'
             WHEN ACTFINISH IS NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), GETDATE())
        END) AS PERFORMANCE
FROM TICKET;
```

"Current date" probably implies only the date component and not the time component, so I perhaps:  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)`.

I also note that your logic looks highly suspicious.  Why are those two conditions both `'Past Due'`?  In any case, that is not your actual question.

Comment: I tried this but it post the CURRENT DATETIME in the PERFORMANCE Column. I wanted the CURRENT DATETIME to be used to compare with TARGCOMPDATE in the place of NULL value of ACTFINISH column and use the results to determine if its 'Past Due" or 'On Time'

Comment: @BongoOne . . . That is not the question that you asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *question*.  Include sample data, desired results, and an explanation.

Comment: I was trying to make it clear what my question really meant, i might not be clear when i asked that's why i decided to make it more clearer. It is not a different question but an explanation to what it meant to achieve. If i were you and i know the answer, it wouldn't matter to answer even if i believe its a new question. Thanks for you time and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BongoOne . . . Your question, as written, appears to be quite clear.  It has attracted three undeleted answers -- not a record, but quite respectable.  If your question does not express what you intend, then ask *another* question.  Work on explaining it better and include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't understand your explanation. From your comments, I wrote this,

```
create table #dateTable(nullColumn date, col1 date, col2 date)

insert into #dateTable values(null,'05-May-2018','05-May-2018') ,('06-May-2018','05-May-2018','05-May-2018') 

select *from #dateTable

select iif(nullColumn is null, 1,0)from #dateTable
-- replace 1 by your current date comparison. And, 0 is must replaced by ACTFINISH date comparison
```

Let me know, what was you got.